# How to brute force HTTP Basic Authentication requested with XHR?

Tags: authentication, http, brute-force, metasploit, http-brute

How can one brute force a website using HTTP Basic authentication using metasploit which uses XHR in background? I am getting error "**No URI found that asks for HTTP authentication**". Relevant headers are as below:

Authorization: Basic ###########
**X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest**

I did not found any relevant Metasploit options to set specific to XHR while using /auxiliary/scanner/http/http_login. Also site uses Ajax/Javascript for form submission.

Also when you visit the `http://hostname:port` it redirects to `http://hostname:port>/#/signin`, is this **#** here of any significance?
P.S. I am using `URI_PATH = /#/signin` as the option with no luck.

Comment: This is fascinating, I have no clue how my actual question asked on Security Stack Exchange, got here http://wordpressthemes.review/how-to-brute-force-http-basic-authentication-requested-with-xhr/ 
Are people allowed to do that?

Comment: Krishna - discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/154443

Comment: You could edit `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/http_login.rb` to include the extra header with the request, or better still you could make a custom module from it with the option to add the header.

Answer (score 3):

Metasploit's http_login module doesn't support arbitrary HTTP headers.  If the site only responds with the XHR header included, then you might want to use a more versatile tool like hydra.

# indicates the beginning of the URI fragment.  This isn't a part of the URI used for logins, but is typically used to pass options to the front-end web framework.

Comment: I have used Hydra to brute-force http-basic authentication with www-authenticate header, will try for XHR one as well and let you know. Thanks.